# What is the yellow coating seen on the sides of containers storing copper Sulphate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

When storing a solution of copper sulphate, a yellow colored deposit slowly formed on the bottom and sides of the container. What/Why could this be?

I'm using it for simple 8th - grade level reactions. Like electroplating, reacting it with iron etc. I'm storing around 250 ml for around a month or less until used.

I suspect some excess Sulphur but I have no way to prove it.

[image]

Comment: I would guess if is hydrolyzed/oxidized/precipitated iron(III) oxide/hydroxide from copper sulphate impurities.

Comment: What would I have to do to prevent this in future? Purify it somehow? Its not a problem, it doesn't really interfere with reactions, but I have to filter it every time I use it, otherwise the solution is really cloudy.

Comment: Provide more context about the purity, purpose, amount or volume, storage interval etc, as the optimal advice may largely depend on that. // Background or context info omitted in too laconic questions has to be frequently clarified later with big effort on all sides.

Comment: I unfortunately can't provide info on purity because the amazon listing did not have any info about it and I'm afraid I don't have the equipment to measure its purity. However, I've added the rest as an edit

Comment: Small volume of added sulphuric acid to keep low enough pH could help.

Comment: Any other alternate?, I'm just doing basic chemistry at home, and I don't have access to sulphuric acid.

Comment: More expensive, but safer to handle than sulfuric acid, is sodium bisulfate, NaHSO4. This used to be available in crystal toilet bowl cleaners, but these have been discontinued. Chemical suppliers should have it, though.

Comment: What is the container made of?

Comment: The one in the picture is made of glass, but I had similar results trying to store it in plastic